# strpos always returning the same value

Tags: php

In both cases it returns    `b`

```
if(strpos('1', "Content-Length: 1 12327225") !== false) {
    echo 'a';
} else {
    echo 'b';
}

if(strpos('foqerwerun', "Content-Length: 1 12327225") !== false) {
    echo 'a';
} else {
    echo 'b';
}
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You're using [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/strpos) incorrectly. The syntax is `strpos(string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ]).` The string you're searching for goes in the second argument, and the string you're searching in goes in the first.

```
if(strpos("Content-Length: 1 12327225", '1') !== false) {
    echo 'a';
} else {
    echo 'b';
}

if(strpos("Content-Length: 1 12327225", '1') !== false) {
    echo 'a';
} else {
    echo 'b';
}
```